# Android: Toggling background on and off

Tags: android, background, drawable

I've got an Android application that has a settings to turn the background images on and off.

However, I've had a user email me saying it creates a bad effect for his device, Galaxy Nexus running 4.0.2 (see https://www.dropbox.com/s/d61wyb325ckia9r/Screenshot_2012-04-19-00-02-27.png )  I'm unable to reproduce the issue in any emulator I have (all version from 2.2 up) or an either of my devices (2.3.7 Nexus One and Evo 4g).

It seems something with the transparency settings is throwing the rendering off.

Below is my code for toggling the background image.

```
void setBackground(){
    if(hideBackground==true){
        getWindow().setBackgroundColor(-16777216);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.black);
    }
    else{
        int pics[] =  {R.drawable.bloodseeker, R.drawable.drow, R.drawable.morphling};
        Random rand = new Random();
        int pos = rand.nextInt(pics.length-1);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(null);
        getWindow().setBackgroundColor(0);
        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(pics[pos]);
    }
}
```

Anyone able to point me in the right direction for fixing this issue?

Comment: Any reason why you're setting the background multiple times in a row? just the one call to setBackgroundDrawableResource(pics[pos]) should work.  Also, the current API has no implementation for window.setBackgroundColor() and the pic you have displayed is running ICS - that function may have been deprecated

Comment: The original code did not have the multiple background changes.  I added them after I was notified it was having issues in an attempt to resolve them.

The original set of code simply had 

        getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(pics[pos]); and getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.black);

Comment: How about setting the background of the root view instead of the window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As JRaymond commented on my original post, setting the background of the root view worked to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to [invalidate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29) your root view after setting the transparent background.